# Sympy Linsolve unexpected results

Tags: python, math, sympy

I am trying to solve a system of equations with Linsolve, but obviously must have misunderstood something, since I keep getting unexpected results. Say I want to solve the two following equations:

```
a + b = 0
a - b + c = 0
```

I would expect the result:

```
b = 0.5*c
```

Instead Sympy returns the empty set. With nonlinsolve I get (-a), which doesn't make much sense either:

```
>>> import sympy
>>> a, b, c = sympy.symbols('a b c')
>>> Eqns = [a + b, a - b + c]
>>>sympy.linsolve(Eqns, b)
()
>>>sympy.nonlinsolve(Eqns, b)
(-a)
```

I think I'm going insane, please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to pass the other variable. So pass as many variables as equations or it's unsolvable, just like by hand.

```
import sympy as sp
a, b, c = sp.symbols('a b c')
Eqns = [a + b, a - b + c]
sp.solve(Eqns, b, a)
```